# Add a level to Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem with a numpy array.

In particular, suppose to have a matrix

```
x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
```

with shape `(2,3)`, I want to convert the float numbers into list so to obtain the array `[[[1.], [2.], [3.]], [[4.], [5.], [6.]]]` with shape `(2,3,1)`.
I tried to convert each float number to a list (i.e., `x[0][0] = [x[0][0]]`) but it does not work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in Numpy to perform exactly what @Valdi_Bo mentions. You can use `np.expand_dims` and add a new dimension along axis 2, as follows:

`x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=2)`

Refer:
[np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is adding another dimension to your numpy array. One way of doing it is using reshape:

```
x = x.reshape(2,3,1)
```

output:

```
[[[1.]
  [2.]
  [3.]]

 [[4.]
  [5.]
  [6.]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you want to add a **dimension** (not *level*).

To do it, run:

```
result = x[...,np.newaxis]
```

Its shape is just `(2, 3, 1)`.

Or save the result back under *x*.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a new dimension to the numpy array. There are multiple ways of doing this as other answers mentioned `np.expand_dims`, `np.new_axis`, `np.reshape` etc. But I usually use the following as *I find it the most readable*, especially when you are working with vectorizing multiple tensors and complex operations involving broadcasting (check this [Bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094234/4755954) that I solved with this method).

```
x[:,:,None].shape

(2,3,1)
```

```
x[None,:,None,:,None].shape

(1,2,1,3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this is an overkill for the array you have, but definitely the most efficient solution is to use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). This way no data is copied.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])

newshape = x.shape[:-1] + (x.shape[-1], 1)
newstrides = x.strides + x.strides[-1:]
a = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=newshape, strides=newstrides)
```

results in:

```py
array([[[1.],
        [2.],
        [3.]],

       [[4.],
        [5.],
        [6.]]])
```

```py
>>> a.shape
(2, 3, 1)
```